# Tornado performance issue with coroutine

Tags: python, tornado

I got performance issue after using coroutine, code is simple as official document:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        httpClient = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        yield httpClient.fetch('http://google.com/', method = 'GET')
```

Test command is:

```
wrk -t12 -c400 -d30s http://10.0.0.10:2002/
```

I can only get 66 requests per second, if I remove `httpClient.fetch()`, I can get 1659 requests per second.
Tornado is running single process on E5-2666 v3 @ 2.90GHz, CPU usage of this process all goes 100%.

I'm using Tornado v4.4.1, python 2.7.

Comment: if you remove this  httpClient.fetch(), Then you are not making request to HTTP or given URL. You are simply creating http client

Comment: refer this : http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.HTTPClient.fetch

Comment: So, how to test real request count with httpClient.fetch() ?

Comment: Sorry,  a little mistake, CPU doesn't go to 100% with httpClient.fetch(), I think it's waiting for httpClient response.

Answer (score 6):

By default, AsyncHTTPClient won't await more than 10 concurrent requests. So if each fetch takes about 150ms between start and finish, for example, that would limit you to about 66 fetches per second total. Since each `MainHandler.get` awaits an `AsyncHTTPClient.fetch`, that means that `get` is bottlenecked too.

Raise the maximum clients like so, at the very beginning of your program:

```
tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.configure(None, max_clients=1000)
```

Do that right after all your imports and before you create any AsyncHTTPClients.

Comment: Oh, this is useful, but I can still get only 200 requests per second. Is it intended, or my test way is wrong?

Comment: In that case you're either hitting your actual peak throughput (limited by your network, or CPU), or else the "-c400" argument to wrk is now your bottleneck and you should raise that, too.